# How to do conditional formatting of a label in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, formatting

I need to format a label value conditionally in "$K" and "$M" when the data is in thousands and millions. I've been using the following format which works absolutely fine in Excel cells ($#,##0.0,"K") and ($#,##0.00,,"M") respectively, this doesnt work when I use it to format a label caption using VBA with the following code :

```
lblInvestmentValue.Caption = Format(CStr(dblInvestmentVal), "[>=1000000] $#,##0.0,,""M"";[>0] $#,##0.0, ""K"";General")
```

On using this I get the following output

```
dblInvestmentVal Caption        Expected Caption
812              $812.0M        $812
8280119          $8,280,119.0M  $8.29M
91281            $12,367.0M     $12.4K
```

Any pointers

Comment: why are you using cstr() here?  why not val()?

Comment: @Sixthsense The dblInvestmentVal variable was a double variable and I was using some concatenation earlier so was converting it to string. I just tried using it with Val() as well just now, doesn't affect the result

Comment: What is the value of dblInvestmentVal textbox?

Comment: @Sixthsense Numbers as shown in example. (See edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an IIF statement.

```
lblInventmentValue.Caption = IIF(Abs(dblInvestmentVal) >= 1000000, Format(dblInvestmentVal / 1000000, "$#,##0.0,,""M"""),IIF(Abs(dblInvestmentVal) >= 1000, Format(dblInvestmentVal / 1000, "$#,##0.0,,""K"""),Format(dblInvestmentVal, "$#,##0.0")))
```

Statement use Abs(dblInventmentVal) to also format negativ numbers correctly.

Comment: Perfect. If I understood correct, i was having an issue becuase of incorrect syntax for condition?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this conditional number formatting is supported by the `format` command, but you could easily replace this with:

```
Function ConditionalFormatNumber(n As Double) As String
    If n > 1000000 Then
        ConditionalFormatNumber = Format(n / 1000000, "$#,##0.00,,""M""")
    ElseIf n > 1000 Then
        ConditionalFormatNumber = Format(n / 1000, "$#,##0.00, ""K""")
    Else
        ConditionalFormatNumber = Format(n, "$#,##0.0")
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The `TEXT` worksheet function seems to respect the format you initially specified and you can use it in your VBA by virtue of `Application.WorksheetFunction`.

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(812, "[>=1000000] $#,##0.0,,""M"";[>0] $#,##0.0, ""K"";General")
```

The [VBA reference for FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) doesn't cover conditional number formatting but it does have a number formatting section, so I expect conditional number formatting isn't valid - although I find it interesting that using it defaults to the first pattern in your specified format.